# Powershell Prompt For Input From Remote User

Tags: powershell, remote-server

I want to run a shutdown command on a remote computer, but I want the user to be prompted to accept or decline the command. This is what I have. It prompts the local user for the $computername, I need to run an input prompt on the remote computer user, then execute the shutdown script.

```
$server=read-host 'Enter Name'
$choice = ""
while ($choice -notmatch "[y|n]"){
$choice = read-host "Do you want to continue? (Y/N)"
}
if($choice -eq "y"){
shutdown /m \\$server /r /t 00
}
else {write-host "Please contact your systems administrator."}
```

Comment: this clearly isn't the way to go, not sure how you would achieve that, tbh, probably `invoke-command` and some winforms magic? I don't know

Comment: The biggest problem you are going to run into is running this interactively in the user's session. Making a scheduled task is most common method.

Comment: Yes, the interactive login makes the shutdown command fail unless I -force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is displaying the message to the user because it has to run interactively in that user session.

One method, if you just want to display a message that the computer is about to shutdown, and you don't want them to be able to cancel, would be to leverage the [remote shutdown command](https://serverfault.com/questions/419301/pop-up-a-message-or-run-a-program-on-remote-windows-7-computer-so-currently-logg):

```
shutdown -m //computername -r -f -c "MESSAGE" -t 120
```

If you need more comprehensive shutdown, where the user can always cancel (and believe me, they will always choose to cancel) the shutdown, then you need to use something like [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) where you run a script in the interactive session:

```
psexec.exe \\computername -I message.vbs
```

Where message.vbs could be whatever more complex script (or PowerShell script) that you need to run.

Comment: In the end I decided to use the shutdown command and prompt the user that they have 5 minutes to save their work before they are forced to shutdown. There is no way to invoke. Maybe pssexec, but i didn't want to deal with sysinternals.

Comment: $server=read-host 'Enter Hostname'

    while ($choice -notmatch "[y|n]"){
    $choice = read-host "If you want to immediately shutdown the         remote computer select yes or if you want to give the user 5 minutes to  prepare for shutdown select no. (Y/N)"}
if($choice -eq "y"){
shutdown  /s /m \\$server /t 00
    }
    if($choice -eq "n"){
    shutdown /s /m \\$server /f /c "Your session needs close immediately   for network security reasons. Please close this message and save your work. The system will shutdown in 5 minutes." /t 300
    }